# parse HTML in Bash (when grep just isn't enough)

Tags: bash, sed, grep, html

This is driving me insane, as I'm sure there must be some program doing the job but I just can't find it.
To be noted, I'd be on ARM/Raspberry so unfortunately `Xidel` is not an option here, unless someone is kind enough to point me in the right direction for compiling it myself (if possible at all). I also tried `w3m` but I'm not quite sure dumping the page to another to-be-formatted file would truly help, but then again please prove me wrong!

Basically I need to read an https url, then parse the html to something easily accessible from within Bash, and finally store some values in a db.
I'm already doing most of the job simply with `grep`, but as soon as the data I need is not exactly how it should be formatted I'm stuck. See example:

```
<h1>Title</h1> #easy to extract Title only with grep | sed

<h1>
Title
</h1> #no way
```

So you can see the catch here, what I need is a script solution that reads the whole page and gives me an array of the contents, rather than the 'randomly' formatted output I currently have.
Thanks everyone

Comment: I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmllint, xmlstarlet ...).

Comment: Customary link to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/297629

Comment: Have a look at the `hxpipe` command from the [HTML-XML-Utils](https://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/).

Answer (score 3):

I would filter the file using [`tidy`](https://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/), to put each top-level tag on a separate line, and use something better suited to this type of scripting (such as Perl) for handling the markup.  `sed` is most useful when the changes are very simple.

For example, a fragment from this page (after filtering) would look like this (using `tidy -wrap 4096` to reduce wrapped lines):

```
<body class="question-page new-topbar">
<noscript>
<div id="noscript-padding"></div>
</noscript>
<div id="notify-container"></div>
<div id="overlay-header"></div>
<div id="custom-header"></div>
<div class="topbar">
<div class="topbar-wrapper">
<div class="js-topbar-dialog-corral">
<div class="topbar-dialog siteSwitcher-dialog dno">
<div class="header">
<h3><a href="//unix.stackexchange.com">current community</a></h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-content current-site-container">
<ul class="current-site">
```

The `"a"` tags, etc., will be inline, but the page structure is simpler to work with.

I "downloaded" the page using `lynx -source`.  You could use a variety of tools however: `wget` and `curl` are more often used for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Have a try at [pup](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup).
i.e. for OSX:

```
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/EricChiang/pup/master/pup.rb
```

You can use CSS3 selector and extractor to get value from `href` attributes.